# Three.js How to find vertices of the face by face index?

Tags: three.js

In my Three.js project i have a mesh using a buffergeometry.

Using raycaster i find the intersection of a ray with this mesh in a specific face of which it says me the index.

How can i find vertices position of this face?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `faceIndex`, it's easier to use the `face` property of an intersection object. You can use it like so:

```
var vA = new THREE.Vector3();
var vB = new THREE.Vector3();
var vC = new THREE.Vector3();

var face = intersection.face;
var geometry = intersection.object.geometry;
var position = geometry.attributes.position;

vA.fromBufferAttribute( position, face.a );
vB.fromBufferAttribute( position, face.b );
vC.fromBufferAttribute( position, face.c );
```

If you need the vertices in world space, then multiple these three vectors with the world matrix of your object.

`three.js R102`

Comment: what exactly is vA.fromBufferAttribute()?

Comment: it is just a way to say that i have to get the value from position array using face.a index?

Comment: It's an instance of `THREE.Vector3`. Let me clarify the post.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge of trying to get the vertices from a triangular face of a raycaster intersection. The accepted answer did not work for me, but getting face property was a good starting approach. I used the object.geometry.vertices index to get the xyz vector information.

```
var vertexElem = intersects[0].face.a;
var x1 = intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[vertexElem].x;
var y1 = intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[vertexElem].y;
var z1 = intersects[0].object.geometry.vertices[vertexElem].z;
```